# TimeOut Conexão Android e SQL Server usando JDBC/JTDS

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc

Gostaria de limitar um tempo para a conexão. Toda vez que ela não encontra o Host para conectar, ela fica tentando e demora.

Eis o código:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {

/*Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "dbuser");
props.setProperty("password", "dbpassword");
props.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "2000");*/

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
Connection conn = null;
String ConnURL = null;
try {
    Class.forName(classs);
    ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
            + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
            + password + ";namedPipe=true;loginTimeout=5;socketTimeout=1";

/*Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("connectTimeout", "2000");*/
    DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
} catch (SQLException se) {
    Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
}
return conn;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se já arranjas-te solução ou não para o que querias, mas sempre podias tentar esta solução dada aqui : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952403/setting-a-login-timeout-when-connecting-to-sql-server-with-android

Edit.

Consegui resolver a minha situação criando um método para me fazer esta verificação.

```
public boolean checkConnetion()
{
    boolean success;
    try
    {
        _driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        _conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("server") + ":" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("port") + "/" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("dbname") +
                ";instance=" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("instance") + ";loginTimeout=2";
        Class.forName(_driver);
        _con = DriverManager.getConnection(_conString, GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("user"), GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("pass"));
        _con.close();
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("checkConnetion", e.toString());
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Tenho isto dentro da Class que tenho para tratar das minhas query e afins que preciso para o SQL, e posso chamar esta função sempre que precisar de fazer uma verificação.

Também poderia ser implementada como private e testar dentro da propria Class, mas preferi testar por fora, visto que têm que ser tudo por AsyncTask

No logcat quando ele não consegue fazer a ligação irá aparecer isto:

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.9 (port 1433) after 2000ms

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/151781)

Comment: Sim sry, enquanto também andava a procura de solução ao ler o http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html encontrei uma solução que funcionou bem para mim, for por como uma resposta.

Comment: O porque de -1 depois de adicionar a resposta ?! faz o que o OP quer -.-